# how to get the console output into a label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, console

So im trying to make a simple pyscript editor and i want to get the console output into a label inside my tkinter wiondow

here is my code so far Thanks!

```
from tkinter import Text, Tk
import os
root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry('1920x1080')
def ok():
    input = text1.get("1.0","end-1c")
    gay = open('data.py', 'w')
    gay.write(input)
    gay.close()
    os.startfile('data.py')


text1 = Text(root, bg="#6B6B6B", height=50, width=200)
text1.place(x=320, y=40)
but1 = Button(root, text="halleo", command=ok).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"get the console output"***: [`startfile(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after... It is hard to tell from your question. I assume by console you mean text area. I took out the file output, but you could put it back in.

```py
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import shlex


def run_command(the_command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(the_command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.stdout.read()
    output = str(output).replace("b'", "").replace("\\n'", "")
    lab1.configure(text=output)


def command():
    the_input = text1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    run_command(the_input)


root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry('1920x1080')
text1 = Text(root, bg="#6B6B6B", height=50, width=200)
text1.place(x=320, y=40)
but1 = Button(root, text="halleo", command=command).pack()
lab1 = Label(root, text="asdf", background='white')
lab1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, but no i meant the console thatpops up if you print something of have an error

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind. I'm assuming you want your program to also start the "console". I'm not sure how you would go about identifying the process and getting the output otherwise, but it may be possible. Look at these resources they may help https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python

Comment: I edited the code to show using the subprocess. I tested it but only with echo hello. If you are expecting a lot more information you may have to use poll() method.